# Error 404 triggered by a listener

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I've got a problem while developing a rather simple app. I have absolutely no idea from where it comes from.

Basically, while trying to load a page from my java application, I get a 404 error from Tomcat when I enable a listener which aims at initializing app-wide data (My DAO). When I disable the listener by commenting the lines out in web.xml, I get a 500 on servlet call (triggered by NPE in init() method due to lack of initialisation through the listener class).

Any idea from where it could come ?

Here are extracts of code

**web.xml**

```
    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mypackage.InitialisationDAOFactory</listener-class>
    </listener>
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewBooking</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.mypackages.NewBooking</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewBooking</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
```

**InitialisationDAOFactory.java**

```
    public class InitialisationDAOFactory implements ServletContextListener
    {
        private static final String ATT_DAO_FACTORY = "daofactory";
        private DAOFactory daoFactory;

            ...

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
        {
            ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
            this.daoFactory = DAOFactory.getInstance();
            context.setAttribute(ATT_DAO_FACTORY, daoFactory);
        }
    }
```

**NewBooking.java**

```
    public class NewBooking extends HttpServlet
    {
        private static final String CONF_DAO_FACTORY = "daofactory";
    ...
        private BookingDAO = daoBooking;
        private TripDAO = daoTrip;

        public void init()
        {
            this.daoBooking = ( (DAOFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute(CONF_DAO_FACTORY)) .getBookingDAO();
            this.daoBooking = ( (DAOFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute(CONF_DAO_FACTORY)) .getBookingDAO();
        }
    ...
    }
```

The 500 happens when the listener is not active (commented out inside web.xml) and thus daofactory not in servletContext, then trying to reach it returns null, and hence an NPU on .getBookingDAO() call.
However, I have absolutely no idea as to where the 404 comes from.

Anyone has an idea as to its origin, and potential corrections ? Thanks

Edit: the app runs on TomCat 7

Edit 2: As stated in comments, I try to access the page by using indifferently `http://localhost/AppName/index` or `http://localhost/AppName` as `index` is declared a welcome file in `web.xml`. The method called should be doGet(request, response) which passes the data to the JSP with `this.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,response);`

I did check that the file existed and was properly named and it might be worth mentionning that another servlet, which behaved properly (both with `doGet` and `doPost`) before that does not respond any more when the filter is active

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to use to access `NewBooking`? What is your context path? What HTTP Method should handle it?

Comment: I try to access indifferently localhost/AppName/index or localhost/AppName as index is declared a welcome file in web.xml. On that call, it should be handled by doGet() which uses `this.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request,response);` to call the jsp

Comment: Are you sure your file is there? Is the 404 for `/WEB-INF/index.jsp`?

Comment: Yes I did check, and no, the 404 is for `/AppName/index`

Comment: The 404 could mean that the webapp failed to start because of an exception in the initialization code. Did you check the Tomcat logs for errors?

Comment: Looking through it right now, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by David Levesque and Martin Strejc, the webapp failed to start because of an exception causing the context to fail.

Through log exploration I found that it was caused by the database driver not being loaded properly thus the `DAOFactory.getInstance()` method to fail and propagating an exception.

Since this was entirely due to not properly setting up my project in the first place, I'm not sure the question si relevant any more.

Answer (score 1):

The listener is running before context starts. If the listener throws an exception your context fails and you see just 404 because there is really no application on the requested URI. See catalina.out enable logging to see what's happen.